# Issues with using \nameref (hyperref) and \mdtheorem (mdframed) together

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, mdframed

When using the `\mdtheorem` command (from `mdframed`) with `\nameref` (from `hyperref`), it seems that labels applied to an theorem made using `\mdtheorem` will not appropriately take the title given to the theorem.  Instead, it takes the title of the current section, as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tikzset{tatregris/.style =
{draw=gray, thick, fill=white, shading = theoremtitle, %
text=gray, rectangle, rounded corners, right,minimum height=.7cm}}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{theorembackground}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(black!2); color(100bp)=(black!15)}
\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
outerlinewidth=0em,outerlinecolor=white,%
leftmargin=-1em,rightmargin=-1em,%
middlelinewidth=1.2pt,roundcorner=5pt,linecolor=gray,
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style ={%
shading = theorembackground}}},
innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
skipbelow={-1em},
needspace=\baselineskip,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\scshape,
}
\makeatother
\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\begin{thm}[Theorem name] \label{theorem name}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}
\nameref{theorem name} is a theorem.
\end{document}
```

Worth noting is that the issue does not exist when using `\newmdtheoremenv` (which is not a valid fix because I need the unnumbered environment given by `\mdtheorem` and I prefer the theorem title being the frame title.)

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allow [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) to extract the name when it sets `thm`. For this we can patch `\thm` (using [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref,xpatch}

\tikzset{tatregris/.style =
  {draw=gray, thick, fill=white, shading = theoremtitle, %
  text=gray, rectangle, rounded corners, right,minimum height=.7cm}}
  \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{theorembackground}{100bp}
  {color(0bp)=(black!2); color(100bp)=(black!15)}

\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
  outerlinewidth=0em,outerlinecolor=white,%
  leftmargin=-1em,rightmargin=-1em,%
  middlelinewidth=1.2pt,roundcorner=5pt,linecolor=gray,
  apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style ={%
  shading = theorembackground}}},
  innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
  skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
  skipbelow={-1em},
  needspace=\baselineskip,
  frametitlefont=\sffamily\scshape,
}

\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newcommand{\thmautorefname}{Theorem}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\thm}{\refstepcounter}{\NR@gettitle{#1}\refstepcounter}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}

\begin{thm}[Theorem name] \label{theorem_name1}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\nameref{theorem_name1} is a named theorem. \autoref{theorem_name2} is not a named theorem.

\begin{thm}\label{theorem_name2}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Of course, if you don't supply a name as the optional argument to `thm`, then `\nameref` will fail. However, you can also use `\autoref` for this.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for!  I had a feeling the solution would be pointing nameref in the right direction, but wasn't too familiar with how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

The generalization of Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219283/16967). The following example
patches `\mdtheorem` to catch all theorems by this command. The code of `\mdtheorem` contains lot of cases, thus the example uses a loop to get all `\ifstrempty`, whose argument is reused to get the title. The example does not set a title, if the title is empty. This can also be changed to use an empty title for `nameref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref,xpatch}

\tikzset{tatregris/.style =
  {draw=gray, thick, fill=white, shading = theoremtitle, %
  text=gray, rectangle, rounded corners, right,minimum height=.7cm}}
  \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{theorembackground}{100bp}
  {color(0bp)=(black!2); color(100bp)=(black!15)}

\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
  outerlinewidth=0em,outerlinecolor=white,%
  leftmargin=-1em,rightmargin=-1em,%
  middlelinewidth=1.2pt,roundcorner=5pt,linecolor=gray,
  apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style ={%
  shading = theorembackground}}},
  innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
  skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
  skipbelow={-1em},
  needspace=\baselineskip,
  frametitlefont=\sffamily\scshape,
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mdfNR@gettitle@ifstrempty}[1]{%
  \ifstrempty{#1}{%
    \@firstoftwo
  }{%
    \NR@gettitle{#1}%
    \@secondoftwo
  }%
}
% Variant: Define title string for nameref regardless of its emptyness
% \newcommand*{\mdfNR@gettitle@ifstrempty}[1]{%
%   \NR@gettitle{#1}%
%   \ifstrempty{#1}%
% }
\count@=\@ne
\@whilenum\count@>\z@\do{%
  \expandafter\xpatchcmd\csname mdtheorem code\endcsname{%
    \ifstrempty%
  }{%
    \mdfNR@gettitle@ifstrempty
  }{%
    \advance\count@\@ne
  }{%
    \count@=-\count@
  }%
}
\ifnum\count@>\z@
\else
  \@latex@warning{Could not patch \string\mdtheorem}%
\fi
\makeatother

\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newcommand{\thmautorefname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}

\begin{thm}[Theorem name] \label{theorem_name1}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\nameref{theorem_name1} is a named theorem. \autoref{theorem_name2} is not a
named theorem.

\begin{thm}\label{theorem_name2}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```